# resize the cell on cell in jointjs

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I have a jointjs demo code, which has basic shapes on paper, i want to increase the size of the shape, or highlight the shape on pointer click or cursor moved on the shape,
sample demo code goes here

```
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({

el: $('#paper'),
width: 650,
height: 400,
gridSize: 20,
model: graph
});

var rb = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
size: { width: 100, height: 40 },
attrs: { text: { text: 'basic.Rect' } }
});
graph.addCell(rb);

var tb = new joint.shapes.basic.Text({
position: { x: 170, y: 50 },
size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
attrs: { text: { text: 'basic.Text' } }
});
graph.addCell(tb);

 var cb = new joint.shapes.basic.Circle({
position: { x: 300, y: 70 },
size: { width: 100, height: 40 },
attrs: { text: { text: 'basic.Circle' } }
});
graph.addCell(cb);

var ib = new joint.shapes.basic.Image({
position: { x: 450, y: 50 },
size: { width: 40, height: 40 },
attrs: {
    text: { text: 'basic.Image' },
    image: { 'xlink:href': 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/betelgeuse/96/224386-folder-image-48.png', width: 48, height: 48 }
}
});
graph.addCell(ib);

var pb = new joint.shapes.basic.Path({
position: { x: 50, y: 150 },
size: { width: 40, height: 40 },
attrs: {
    path: { d: 'M25.979,12.896 19.312,12.896 19.312,6.229 12.647,6.229 12.647,12.896 5.979,12.896 5.979,19.562 12.647,19.562 12.647,26.229 19.312,26.229 19.312,19.562 25.979,19.562z' },
    text: { text: 'basic.Path' }
}
});
graph.addCell(pb);

var rh = new joint.shapes.basic.Rhombus({
position: { x: 50, y: 250 },
size: { width: 70, height: 70 },
attrs: { text: { text: 'basic.Rhombus', 'font-size': 8 } }
});
graph.addCell(rh);

var tbl = new joint.shapes.basic.TextBlock({
position: { x: 400, y: 180 },
size: { width: 180, height: 100 },
content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel porttitor est."
});
graph.addCell(tbl);


// An example of a custom element.
// -------------------------------

var MyElementWithPorts = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.extend({

  defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({

   markup: [
       '<g class="rotatable">',
       '<g class="scalable">',
       '<rect/>',
       '</g>',
       '<g class="inPorts">',
       '<g class="port1"><circle/><text/></g>',
       '<g class="port2"><circle/><text/></g>',
       '</g>',
       '<g class="outPorts">',
       '<g class="port3"><circle/><text/></g>',
       '<g class="port4"><circle/><text/></g>',
       '</g>',
       '</g>'
   ].join(''),

   type: 'basic.Generic',
   attrs: {
       '.': { magnet: false },
       rect: {
           width: 150, height: 250,
           stroke: 'black'
       },
       circle: {
           r: 5,
           magnet: true,
           stroke: 'black'
       },
       text: {
           fill: 'black',
           'pointer-events': 'none'
       },
       '.label': { text: 'Model', dx: 5, dy: 5 },
       '.inPorts text': { dx:-15, 'text-anchor': 'end' },
       '.outPorts text':{ dx: 15 },
       '.inPorts circle': { fill: 'PaleGreen' },
       '.outPorts circle': { fill: 'Tomato' }
   }

 }, joint.shapes.basic.Generic.prototype.defaults)
});

var d = new MyElementWithPorts({
position: { x: 250, y: 150 },
size: { width: 80, height: 80 },
attrs: {
    '.port1 text': { text: 'port1' },
    '.port2 text': { text: 'port2' },
    '.port3 text': { text: 'port3' },
    '.port4 text': { text: 'port4' },
    '.port1': { ref: 'rect', 'ref-y': .2 },
    '.port2': { ref: 'rect', 'ref-y': .4 },
    '.port3': { ref: 'rect', 'ref-y': .2, 'ref-dx': 0 },
    '.port4': { ref: 'rect', 'ref-y': .4, 'ref-dx': 0 }        
}
});

graph.addCell(d);


// An example showing auto-resize of the joint.shapes.basic.Rect element based on the size of the text in it:

rb.on('change:attrs', function(element) {

var text = rb.attr(' /text');
var fontSize = parseInt(rb.attr('text/font-size'), 10);

var svgDocument = V('svg').node;
var textElement = V('<text><tspan></tspan></text>').node;
var textSpan = textElement.firstChild;
var textNode = document.createTextNode('');

textSpan.appendChild(textNode);
svgDocument.appendChild(textElement);
document.body.appendChild(svgDocument);

var lines = text.split('\n');
var width = 0;

// Find the longest line width.
_.each(lines, function(line) {

    textNode.data = line;
    var lineWidth = textSpan.getComputedTextLength();

    width = Math.max(width, lineWidth);
});

var height = lines.length * (fontSize * 1.2);

V(svgDocument).remove();

element.resize(width + 10, height);
});

paper.on('cell:pointerdown', 
function(cellView, evt, x, y) { 
//cellView.model.resize(cellView.model.height+2, cellView.model.width+2);
    cellView.model.resize(width + 10, height);  
    //rb.scale(rb.x+10,rb.y+10);        
    cellView.highlight(cellView.model.id);


}

);
paper.on('cell:pointerup', 
function(cellView, evt, x, y) {  
                //element.resize(width + 10, height);
    //          cellView.model.resize(cellView.model.width-2, cellView.model.height-2);
    cellView.unhighlight(cellView.model.id);    
}

);
```

I am new bee to jointjs.

i tried to resize the shape but it is not working

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdown', 
function(cellView, evt, x, y) { 
    alert('cell view ' + cellView.model.id + ' was clicked'); 
        var bbox = cellView.getBBox();
var strokeWidth = cellView.model.attr('rect/stroke-width') || 1;
console.log(isBorderClicked(bbox, x, y, strokeWidth))
    //cellView.model.id.resize(width + 10, height);

}
```

highlighting is happening by the click on the cell:

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdown', 
function(cellView, evt, x, y) { 
   // alert('cell view ' + cellView.model.id + ' was clicked' ); 
    cellView.highlight(cellView.model.id)    
        //element.resize(width + 10, height);

}

);
paper.on('cell:pointerup', 
function(cellView, evt, x, y) { 
    //alert('cell view ' + cellView.model.id + ' was released' ); 
    cellView.unhighlight(cellView.model.id)    
        //element.resize(width + 10, height);

}
```

But i want to resize the cell. when i click on the cell i should be able to resize the cell

please help me out solving this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have it almost right but you're calling the `resize()` method on the ID of the element which is a string. You should do:

> cellView.model.resize(width + 10, height);

I also don't see in your example where are your `width` and `height` variables defined?
In general, in JointJS there are models and views. For example, the `highlight()` is a method of a view (http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.ElementView:highlight) and the `resize()` is a method of the element model (http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:resize). From views, you can always get to models by accessing the `view.model` property.

Comment: Hi dave, thanks for the reply. yo solution some what helped me, i have posted the complete example what i want is when i click on the cell i should be able to drag the cell and resize it. what is happening is, it is resizing to a perticular hight and width. i am not able to resize it. i want to drag the cell corner and resize the cell.

Comment: @dave how can I extend the core version to allow user to resize using any sides of an element view? I understand it's a feature of your commercial product but how can I achieve this via core?

Comment: @SiddharthPandey, with the new version of JointJS, it should be now fairly easy to do using the dia.Element.resize() method. This method has been extended with numerous options for resizing to all the sides. See http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:resize